# Unable to load the layers in Mapbox because of API GET request error

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I have tried to develop a webmapping interface which will enable me to select the the base map style which will also add the call center employee population to the map. It will be in the form of graduate symbols, where larger the circle means more no. of employees. When I inspected the webpage, it shows "{"message":"id must be a string with the format account.handle"}.

Screenshot of webpage is attached. Code is below [image: Webpage Here][image: Webpage]

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title>Active Call Centers of IBEX</title>
      <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.41.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
      <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
      <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.41.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <link href='https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <style>
         h2, h3 {
              margin-left: 10px;
              font-size: 1.5em;
              font-family: Tahoma;
              font-weight: 100;
              font-style: bold;
          }
          h3 {
              font-size: 1em;
          }
          p {
              font-size: 0.85em;
              margin-left: 10px;
              text-align: left;
              font-family: Tahoma;
              font-weight: 100;
              font-style: bold;
          }

          .map-maker {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
              margin-left: 20px;
              font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
              overflow: auto;
              border-radius: 3px;
          }

          #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
          }

          #menu {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 270px;
            padding: 10px;   

            margin-left: 1400px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            /*font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;*/
            font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
            font-style:bold;

          }

          #locations {
            position: absolute;
          }

          #features {
            top: 0;
            height: 80px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 400px;
          }

          .block{
            margin:10px;
          }

           .legend {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            bottom: 30px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
            font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            z-index: 5;
          }

          .legend h4 {
            margin: 0 0 10px;
          }

          .legend p {
            margin-left: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
          }

          .legend div {
            position:relative;
          }

          .legend div span {
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 5px;
            opacity:0.8;
            background-color:#e54343;
          }

          .mapboxgl-popup {
          max-width: 400px;
          font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          }

      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id='map'></div>
      <div id='menu'>

        <h4><b>BaseMap Style</b></h4>
        <label class="block" for='basic'></label>
        <input id='basic' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='basic'>

        <label class="block" for='streets'></label>
        <input id='streets' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='streets'>

        <label class="block" for='bright'></label>
        <input id='bright' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='bright'>

        <label class="block" for='light'></label>
        <input id='light' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='light'>

        <label class="block" for='dark'></label>
        <input id='dark' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='dark'>

        <label class="block" for='outdoors'></label>
        <input id='outdoors' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='outdoors'>

        <label class="block" for='satellite'></label>
        <input id='satellite' type='button' name='rtoggle' value='satellite'>
      </div>
      <div id= 'legend' class='legend'>
        <h4>CallCenterEmployees</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='map-maker' id='features'>
        <h2>Active Call Centers of IBEX in the US</h2>
        <div id='pd'>
          <p>Try clicking on a circle!! </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicnZnMjk2IiwiYSI6ImNqN2h1Y25xbzFqamQzMnJzNTZ6MDY4cjIifQ.5BhBmexjsinKbR6c5VNWXA'; // Put your Mapbox Public Access token here

      // Load a new map in the 'map' HTML div
      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', 
        center: [-115.125,36.111],
        zoom: 10
      });

      var layerList = document.getElementById('menu');
      var inputs = layerList.getElementsByTagName('input');

      function switchLayer(layer) {
          var layerId = layer.target.id;
          map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId + '-v9');  

      }


      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].onclick = switchLayer;
      }




      // Store an array of quantiles
      var max = 1755;
      var fifth = 1755/5;
      var quantiles = [];
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var quantile = (i+1)*fifth;
        quantiles.push(quantile);
      }

      // Add a Geocoder
      map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
      }));

      //Navigation Control
      map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({ position: 'top-left' }));

      var minRadius = 2;
      var maxRadius = 10;
      var minEmployee = 37;
      var maxEmployee = 1755;

      var rateOfChange = (maxRadius - minRadius) / (maxEmployee - minEmployee);

      var radiusAtZero = maxRadius - (rateOfChange * maxEmployee);

      var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
      function circleSize(quantile) {
        var radius = (rateOfChange * quantile) + radiusAtZero;
        var diameter = radius * 2;
        return diameter;
      }
      quantiles.forEach(function(quantile) {
        legend.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div><span style="width:' + circleSize(quantile) + 'px;height:' + circleSize(quantile) + 'px;margin: 0 ' + [(20 - circleSize(quantile)) / 2] + 'px"></span><p>' + quantile + '</p></div>');
      });

      // Load the vector tile source from the Mapbox Employee example 

      map.on('style.load', function() {

        map.addSource('employee_volume',{
          type: 'vector',
          url: 'mapbox://mapbox.rvg296.b4uxfk6x' 
        });
        // Add the circle layer to the map
        map.addLayer({
          'id': 'employee_volume',
          'type': 'circle',
          'source': 'employee_volume',
             // Your Mapbox tileset Map ID
          'source-layer': 'IBEX_Active_Call_Center_List_-16iz6x', // name of tilesets
          'paint': {
            'circle-color': '#e54343',
            // Add data-driven styles for circle radius
            'circle-radius': {
              property: 'Employees',
              type: 'exponential',
              stops: [
                [37,2],
                [1755,10]
              ]
            },
            'circle-opacity': 0.5,
            'circle-stroke-color': 'white',
            'circle-stroke-width': 2,
          }
        });

      // When a click event occurs near a place, open a popup at the location of
      // the feature, with HTML description from its properties
      map.on('click', function(e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['employee_volume'] });

        // if the features have no info, return nothing
        if (!features.length) {
          return;
        }

        var feature = features[0];  

        // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
        // based on the feature found
        var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML('<div id=\'popup\' class=\'popup\' style=\'z-index: 10;\'> <h5> Detail: </h5>' +
        '<ul class=\'list-group\'>' +
        '<li class=\'list-group-item\'> Building Name: ' + feature.properties['Building Name'] + ' </li>' +
        '<li class=\'list-group-item\'> Address: ' + feature.properties['Address'] + ' </li>' + 
        '<li class=\'list-group-item\'> State: ' + feature.properties['State'] +
        '<li class=\'list-group-item\'> Zip: ' + feature.properties['Zip'] + 
        '<li class=\'list-group-item\'> No.of Employees: ' + feature.properties['Employees'] + ' </li></ul></div>')
        .addTo(map);
      });

      // Use the same approach as above to indicate that the symbols are clickable
      // by changing the cursor style to 'pointer'
      map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
        var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['employee_volume'] });
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = features.length ? 'pointer' : '';
      });
    });



    // Full Screen Control
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());

    // Geolocate us
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true

    // Navigation Control

}));
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```